# Configuration of Celery Multi Node with rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery node which using rabbitMQ as a broker, it works fine in one machine. I want to setup a celery node in another machine but it will use the same rabbitMQ broker.

Does that mean if I send a request from the new machine and there are about 1M request waiting in queue the new request should wait until the end of those 1M requests?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you make the new node subscribe to a new queue. Make sure you send new tasks to this new queue instead and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I will do it.